# Passing a PHP variable as a parameter using HTML onClick

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

I looked through many similar examples, but I could not make this work.

So, I have this:

```
echo('<td colspan="3" style="background-color:#005673; text-align:right; padding: 4px 0px;">
      <button class="btnTrack" onClick="trackIt(' . $name . ')" >Track It!</button></td>');
```

That code is inside a for, so the variable $name will be different depending where I am at.

I am not trying to make things complicates, so first, I am just trying to pass that parameter to the function trackIt (I actually need to pass 2 of them.)

Then, I have a simple script (just to see if it will work):

```
<script>
//After you click on Track It

function trackIt(param) 
{
   alert("Hi!");
   alert(param);
}

</script>
```

However, it does not work.

If my `onClick` function is just `onClick="trackIt()"`, then it works fine and I can alert "Hi!" by removing the parameter.

Thanks for the help! =]

Comment: Look at the generated html for more clues

Comment: You forgot to put quotes around your inserted variable. e.g. you're doing `foo(bar)`, making bar an undefined variable, instead of `foo('bar')`, making bar a string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this..

```
echo('<td colspan="3" style="background-color:#005673; text-align:right; padding: 4px 0px;">
  <button class="btnTrack" onclick="trackIt(\'' . $name . '\')" >Track It!</button></td>');
```

Note: you have to use your way if the input parameter is a numeric value..

---

You are printing HTML as,

```
<td colspan="3" style="background-color:#005673; text-align:right; padding: 4px 0px;">
<button class="btnTrack" onclick="trackIt(test)" >Track It!</button></td>
```

But because the function trackIt needs a string as the input parameter, you have to print this..

```
<td colspan="3" style="background-color:#005673; text-align:right; padding: 4px 0px;">
<button class="btnTrack" onclick="trackIt('test')" >Track It!</button></td>
```

As you are using `'` as boundaries to define strings in PHP, you have to escape it using `\'` in order to make `'` character part of the string.

Comment: Now, I need to pass a second parameter using `onclick="trackIt(\'' . $name . '\')" `, should I create a different post for that question?

Comment: @Felipe see if you can figure out how to pass another parameter first.

Comment: I tried a few different things, but it did not work. Then, I read all of the comments again to better understand how it works, and thanks to @plbsam's new explanation, I was able to achieve it. Thanks guys! =]

Comment: Great.. Better you not to ask question without trying.. Otherwise you will not survive when stackoverflow is dead.. :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason this doesn't work is due to the fact that you're passing an unencapsulated string as an argument in your HTML, however, it's being interpreted as a javascript variable, such as:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ValueOf$name is not defined
```

'
Or if the variable contains spaces or special characters:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

To resolve this, you should encapsulate your string with quotations.

```
"trackIt(\'' . $name . '\')"
```

If you're using an integer, string encapsulation is not required.

[jsFiddle examples](http://jsfiddle.net/wvbkzfcz/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however, `"trackIt(\"' . $name . '\")"` does not work!

Comment: `"trackIt(\"' . $name . '\")"` won't work because you can't escape double-quotes in an attribute that's encapsulated with double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

For passing multiple parameters you can cast the string by concatenating it with the ASCII value like, for single quotes we can use `&#39`

```
var str= "&#39;"+ str+ "&#39;";
```

This works for me.

Answer (score -3):

Even if other answers are true... If you do not need to really print all that html use php differently

```
echo('<td colspan="3" style="background-color:#005673; text-align:right; padding: 4px 0px;">
      <button class="btnTrack" onClick="trackIt(' . $name . ')" >Track It!</button></td>');
```

it can become:

```
<td colspan="3" style="background-color:#005673; text-align:right; padding: 4px 0px;">
          <button class="btnTrack" onClick="trackIt(<?php print $name;?>)" >Track It!</button></td>
```

Use php only when needed :)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem - the generated HTML will still be broken.